# Recover from running "route -f"

Tags: windows, route

I was trying to capture localhost traffic with Ethereal, which doesn't work without re-routing localhost traffic to your router gateway.  I didn't get the `route` command quite right, and messed up my routing table.  I typed `route -f` to clear the routing table and rebooted, but when I finished rebooting, the routing table wasn't restored to its original state.  I didn't use the `-p` parameter, so none of my changes should have persisted after a reboot.

What can I do to restore the routing table to its default routes?

Comment: Ethereal? Don't you mean [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)?

Comment: Ethereal and Wireshark are both protocol analyzers.

Comment: Ethereal was _renamed_ Wireshark many years ago. If you're still using Ethereal, you have a real antique on your hands. And the provided link provides several possible ways of monitoring local traffic without messing with your routing table.

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know that.  I'll take a look.  Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that because I had setup the IPv4 settings for the NIC to use static values, Windows didn't completely rebuild the routing table when I rebooted.  I changed the NIC to get its address from the DHCP server, which rebuilt the routing table, then I set it back to static values again and rebooted.  The routing table is fine now.

Comment: As a side note: This is the gentleman who created Ethereal... which went on to become Wireshark - http://serverfault.com/users/9470/gerald-combs